# Using GAE on eclipse after I change a class the changes wont show at run after I restart eclipse. Why?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt

Why do I need to restart eclipse after I change class using gae so the changes show at run?

Comment: Maybe you have deactivated auto build?

Comment: Nop build automatically its check. When I change the jsp files I can see the results right away but when I change the .java files I need to restart eclipse before run as web application